# Google App engine-Redislabs Go runtime production error - invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference

Tags: google-app-engine, go, redislabs

I'm using the Redis Cloud service (from Redis Labs) on Google App engine Go Runtime , and I get the above mentioned error when I try getting a key that doesn't exist. The code works fine on the local test server, but  panics in production.

```
 c, err := redis.Dial("tcp", "pub-redis-myredis:<myport>")
_, err = c.Do("AUTH", "password") 
value, err := c.Do("GET", "foo4")

if value == nil {
    log.Infof(contextOfAppEngineWhereServerIsRunning, "value not found in redislabs")

}
```

The log shows that the panic is in the line `_, err = c.Do("AUTH", "password")`

Comment: Check each returned `error`. Currently in the code you posted you check none.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On AppEngine your application (webapp) runs in a sandboxed environment where you can't use the standard [`net`](https://golang.org/pkg/net/) package for sockets (which I assume redislabs use).

You have to use the [`appengine/socket`](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/go/sockets/reference) package for outbound network sockets.

It most likely works locally because the restriction only applies in production environment.

Always check returned `error` values. Currently in the code you posted you check none. Should you have checked it, you would see the cause from the error.

You get `invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference` error because your first call fails:

```
c, err := redis.Dial("tcp", "pub-redis-myredis:<myport>")
```

`err` will be a non-`nil` value and `c` is `nil` which means you can't call it's `Do()` method.

Comment: Yes , you are right .. Its the restriction by app engine to not to allow outgoing socket calls by standard net package